# How to add Android-ViewPagerIndicator library to maven project

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, project, android-viewpager

I download the library https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator , import to eclipse(Spring tools) , i added to my project in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.viewpagerindicator</groupId>
      <artifactId>library</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.1</version>
      <type>apklib</type>
    </dependency>
```

When i wan`t to import on my project she give me error : The import com.viewpagerindicator cannot be resolved. 
On maven dependency doesn't appear viewpageridicator library!
Thanks in advice !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for apklib dependencies in ADT Eclipse is part of ongoing work for the m2e-android project and is not yet complete. Please comment on this issue to stay updated:

https://github.com/rgladwell/m2e-android/issues/8